# What is the contradiction here…? (Algebra)

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

The following is from a book:

> ***Theorem:*** The set $G_n$ of nonzero elements of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ that are not $0$ divisors forms a group under multiplication modulo $n$.
>
> ***Proof:*** First we must show that $G_n$ is closed under multiplication modulo $n$. Let $a,b \in G_n$. If $ab \notin G_n$ then there would exist $c \neq 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n$ such that $(ab)c = 0$. Now $(ab)c = 0$ implies that $a(bc) = 0$. Since $b \in G_n$ and $c \neq 0$ we have $bc \neq 0$ by definition of $G_n$. But then $a(bc) = 0$ **would imply that $a \notin G_n$ contrary to assumption**. […]

Why is that a contradiction? I thought we assumed $a \in G_n - \{0
\}$, so what are they talking about?

Comment: The theorem is sloppily written. It should be _zero divisor_.

Comment: We assumed $a \in G_n$ and then we proved $a \not \in G_n$.  That's a contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof is unnecessarily involved, mainly because an argument by contradiction is used. Let's try the more general result:

> If $R$ is a commutative ring, the subset $S\subseteq R$ consisting of non zero divisors is closed under multiplication

Let $a,b\in S$ and let $c\in R$; if $(ab)c=0$, then $a(bc)=0$ and so $bc=0$ by the hypothesis $a\in S$; therefore $c=0$ by the hypothesis $b\in S$. Hence $ab$ is not a zero divisor, that is, $ab\in S$.

Comment: This is much cleaner and straightforward. I should really consider switching books lol

Answer (score 4):

If $a(bc)=0$, then $a$ is a zero divisor (or zero) - but then $a\not\in G_n$, since $G_n$ is the set of all elements which **are not** zero divisors (or zero). This is a contradiction, since at the outset we assume $a$ is in fact in $G_n$, i.e. not a zero divisor (or zero).

Comment: Never mind, I was chasing myself in circles.

Comment: FYI if 0<a<n then a belongs to $G_n$ iff gcd(a,n)=1.

Answer (score 0):

The general issue I see is that you think that $0\in G_n$ which it isn't. The rest is then just showing that $a\in G_n$ and that $a\notin G_n$